# Select paragraph using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of `<p>` inside a `<div id="someDiv">`

I use this code to hide all

in the div except the first one

```
$("#someDiv p:not(:first)").hide();
```

I want to change the code to do the following:

Check if `<p>` inside `<div id="someDiv">` is more than 5. If it is, hide all div except first 4 ones.

How to write jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [greater-than](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/gt#index)/[less-than](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lt#index) selectors:

```
$("#someDiv p:lt(4)").hide(); /* hides 0, 1, 2, 3 */
```

That would hide all paragraphs less than the fifth. To determine whether or not there's 5 or more paragraphs, you'll check the [length property](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/length):

```
if ($("#someDiv p").length > 5) {
  $("#someDiv p:gt(3)").hide(); /* hides 4, 5, 6... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan..I want to Show the first four and I also do not know how many <p> are there in teh div..When I use this it does not work for some reason

$("#someDiv p:not(:lt(4))").hide();

Comment: You're making this too complicated. Don't use :not(:lt()) blah blah. Just use :gt(4) - that will select all elements with an index greater than 4.